# Objective-c PDF rendering

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

How can i reduce the size of PDF being rendered using `[v.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];`
Right now, I am rendering a 10 pages PDF with 20 images(2 of each page) and the size is 2.7mb. How can I reduce it to less than 2 mb?

Thanks!

Comment: You really can't. Because of the way that `renderInContext:` works, it creates a PDF form the images created, not from text in a layer.

Comment: So is there no way I can reduce the size of the PDF?

Answer (score 1):

from RR's comment, you can try to reduce a little quality of each image before doing the conversion to PDF.  Like this:

lowResImage = [UIImage imageWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(highResImage, quality)];

Make quality < 1.0 etc.